# Wine "no program is configured to open files of this type"

Tags: wine

Linux Mint.

Im trying to execute `adobe-photoshop-2020.exe`, but I always have this error. I tried to execute `Office-2016-word-excel-powerpoint-x32.exe` and get the same error. But when I tried to download EA launcher cross "Bottles", it opened, but it was broken and non functional. How to fix it?

How it looks in terminal:

```shellsession
$ wine adobe-photoshop-2020.exe
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0024:fixme:shell:SHAutoComplete stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00010050, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010078, 00010050): stub
0024:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000180
0024:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000180
006c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010026, 0): stub
006c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000010026): stub
$ file adobe-photoshop-2020.exe
adobe-photoshop-2020.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Copy&paste the command you run with the error message to your question. Do you get the error with every .exe file or only with a specific one? Show the output of `file your_program.exe`.